# Python module, pyttsx3 not recognised in VS code or pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

I am trying to make a bot that responds to certain question asked like ‘what is the time’ . I am trying to use pyttsx3 module to make it work but this error is coming:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/HarAd MAC/Desktop/Projects/Python_Work/bot.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyttsx
ImportError: No module named pyttsx3
```

I have download the module and checked it in VS code Terminal. It is also showing Requirement already satisfied. Can someone help me in this problem. Same error was shown when I was trying to run it in pycharm. These type of problems have also occurred when using modules that have to be download manually.

I am using MacBook Air big Sur and python 3.9.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if you're using the correct interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but I believe when your import the library you have to do `import pyttsx3` while what you were doing is `import pyttsx`. [Here's](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/) some more info on usage and how to import